# import local module in tornado app

Tags: python, import, tornado, importerror

I have the following tornado app:

```
tornado
   | dmi
      |- __init__.py
      |- functions.py
   | static
      | css
   |- main.py
```

in my main.py file, I would like to import the functions.py file. It's possible? I'm using tornado in virtualenv.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpclient
import dmi.functions
```

when I run the main.py file, I got the following error:

```
import dmi.functions 
ImportError: No module named dmi.functions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
from dmi import functions
```

Comment: It worked. But works with import dmi.functions too. It was a misunderstood. The functions.py file was not in the correctly path.